# BigQuery SPLIT() and grouping by result

Tags: google-bigquery

Using `SPLIT()` & `NTH()`, I'm splitting a string value, and taking the 2nd substring as the result. I then want to group on that result. However, when I use SPLIT() in conjunction with a GROUP BY, it keeps giving the error:

```
Error: (L1:55): Cannot group by an aggregate
```

The result is a string, so why is it not possible to group on it?

For example, this works and returns the correct string:

```
SELECT NTH(2,SPLIT('FIRST-SECOND','-')) as second_part FROM [FOO.bar] limit 10
```

[image]

But then grouping on the result does not work:

```
SELECT NTH(2,SPLIT('FIRST-SECOND','-')) as second_part FROM [FOO.bar] GROUP BY second_part limit 10
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess would be that you can get an equivalent result by using a subquery. Something like :

```
SELECT * FROM (Select NTH(2,SPLIT('FIRST-SECOND','-')) as second_part FROM [FOO.bar] limit 10) GROUP BY second_part
```

The system returns Nth in an aggregate internally I guess

Answer (score 4):

If there are always just 2 values separated by a delimeter, then a simpler approach would be to use REGEXP_EXTRACT:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('FIRST-SECOND','-(.*)') as second_part 
from [FOO.bar] 
GROUP BY second_part 
limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I like David's answer - sometimes splitting can get a bit more complicated using RegEx. Extracting the first option from a split command, then GROUPing BY is a very common operation. The way I normally do this in BigQuery is using a REGEXP_EXTRACT as follows:

In this simple example, the column "splitme" is pipe-delimited (|).

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(splitme, r'(?U)^(.*)\|') AS title, COUNT(*) as c
FROM [my_table]
GROUP BY title;
```

This means, extract the string from the beginning of "splitme" to the first occurrence of a pipe (|). The "(?U)" is the "un-greedy" match flag in the re2 RegEx engine's syntax. Without this flag, if there are multiple pipe-delimited values, this RegEx would match everything up until the last pipe.

Comment: small correction - to extract second value (as it is in question) should be `REGEXP_EXTRACT(splitme,  r'(?U)^.*\|(.*)\|')`

Answer (score 0):

In my practice, I am usually using something like below with N being number of values in "list" to skip.

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(string + '|',  r'(?U)^(?:.*\|){N}(.*)\|') AS substring
```

So if I would be interested in third value in list I would use:

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(string + '|',  r'(?U)^(?:.*\|){2}(.*)\|') AS substring,
  COUNT(1) AS weight
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY 1
```

More details on re2 syntax [here](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)